# Application::ProductName returns a void String

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

When I try to get the application name using

```
Application::ProductName
```

It returns me a void String^. How can I fill this value? (not on runtime)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your project, look for the file `AssemblyInfo.cpp`.

Open the file and look for `AssemblyProductAttribute`.

```
[assembly:AssemblyProductAttribute("YOUR-PRODUCT-NAME")];
```

Replace "YOUR-PRODUCT-NAME" with your desired name.

And the usage:

```
String^ productName= Application::ProductName;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't find AssemblyInfo.cpp on my folder

Comment: It is available in "source files" directory of your project in visual studio. Please look for it.